# 'CompareEndTodayValidator' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, date

I have a calender control ,when selecting a date it should be displayed on an associated text box in "dd-mm-yyyy" format . And have a compare validator which should validate the selected  date ,if it is greater than today's date. I have written like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_date" BackColor="White" ></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:Calendar ID="EndDate" runat="server" 
                   OnSelectionChanged="EndDate_OnSelectionChanged" 
       </asp:Calendar>
            <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="CompareEndTodayValidator" ErrorMessage="Exam date can't be less than today" 
ControlToValidate="tb_date"   Type="Date" Operator="LessThanEqual" >                </asp:CompareValidator> 


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 CompareEndTodayValidator.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
}

   protected void EndDate_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //COMPARE VALIDATOR FOR EXAM DATE
{

    tb_date.Text = EndDate.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
 }
```

It Shows an error

> The value '26-09-2013' of the ValueToCompare property of
>   'CompareEndTodayValidator' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.

Please help. I have tried it with by changing type="string". but failed.When putting mm-dd-yyyy frmat it works properly .But I need in dd-mm-yyyy format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the date format that you are converting your selected calendar value to is NOT compatible with the default `DateTime.Parse`, which is what the Comparer validator no doubt uses internally. Use a different date format or else use the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control so you can control the date parse format manually.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("26-09-2013"); // Fails
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT - Using Custom Validator**

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CompareEndTodayValidatorCust" OnServerValidate="ServerValidation" ControlToValidate="tb_date" ValidateEmptyText="True" ErrorMessage="Exam date can't be less than today" />

protected void ServerValidation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs arguments)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    string format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    DateTime dtToValidate = DateTime.ParseExact(tb_date.Text, format, provider);

     arguments.IsValid = (dtToValidate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
}
```

P.S.

Also in the form submit handler or page load method you'll want to check that `Page.IsValid == true` before allowing the save operation to proceed.

P.S.S

If you want to get more fancy you could provide a JavaScript method in the `ClientValidationFunction` property and validate client side too. That may be overkill though.

Comment: Can you help me by write it with custom validator @James

Comment: I have done like this. not working. Control is not going to  ServerValidation ()

Comment: Add `ValidateEmptyText="True"` to the custom validator control as well, it should work. `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(v=vs.85).aspx`. Post your full markup and codebehind if it's still not.

Comment: when putting break points, it can see that the   arguments.IsValid works properly according to the condition given. but even when the validation failed it navigates to next page instead of showing the ErrorMessage="Exam date can't be less than today" @James

Comment: How are you rendering your paging links are they doing postbacks or are they just links? If they are just links validation isn't going to happen, which is true of all validator controls. If you can use postbacks you can check `Page.IsValid` (which factors in your cust validator result) in the page postback handler. Furthermore, linking paging to validation is not in the scope of this question.

Comment: Why would you want it to validate on page change anyways? A better design would only validate when a save button or link is clicked for the form (or row form) being edited. I think what you need to look into is a unsaved data warning but that's not in the scope of this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Try with **CustomValidator** like following

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_date" BackColor="White" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Calendar ID="EndDate" runat="server" 
           OnSelectionChanged="EndDate_OnSelectionChanged" ></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid date">
</asp:CustomValidator><br />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void EndDate_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //COMPARE VALIDATOR FOR EXAM DATE
{
    CustomValidator1.IsValid = true;
    DateTime SelectedDate = EndDate.SelectedDate.Date;
    DateTime NowDate = DateTime.Now;
    tb_date.Text = SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    if (SelectedDate.Date > NowDate.Date)
    {
        CustomValidator1.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```